t() function with non-English languages
I'm working on a multilingual site. I'm Italian and, for some reasons, I would like to use strings in Italian in code (PHP and Twig), not in English.
I've tried this code in a preprocess function.
$variables['test'] = t('Questa stringa è in italiano', [], ['langcode' => 'it', 'context' => 'my_context']);

If I go to admin/config/regional/translate and I look for this string, it's in English, and I have to translate it in Italian.
Is there a way to have Italian as "default language" in code?

There isn’t, it’s hard-coded to require English. The parameters for TranslatableMarkup::__construct (which is what t() returns) confirm:

string $string: A string containing the English text to translate.

